# How to implement BLOC properly in this example

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am still trying to understand how a "clean" BLOC design would be built. I am confused as to what goes in repositories, what goes in BLOC.

Let's say I have an app which fetches its settings initially from a server, and stores them locally.

If I have the following:

- repositories:

  - local_storage: knows where to read/write settings
  - server_apis: knows how to interact with the server's APIs
- BLOCs:

  - app_init_status: conditions the display, potentially lets the user enter a user account etc...

Where would be the logic which, upon init, reads the local_storage, and figures out if a server API call is needed (and launches it automatically)?

Would it go in the BLOC, even though it is not directly linked to displaying data, or would it be a third 'app_config' repository, talking directly to local_storage and server_apis ?

When we call the server APIs and get our config data back, who would relay that data back to local_storage to store it?

I do not believe this is an opinion based question, as it is a pretty basic use case used to illustrate how BLOC is used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's depend on situation, but most cases you can use local storage repository inside server_api repository and then use server_api repository inside bloc